# Python 3.5 Parent Module Not Found

Tags: import, python-3.5

In Python 3.5, for a directory structure that looks like this:

```
.
└── project
    └── __init__.py
    └── project.py
    └── module1
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module1.py
    └── module2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module2.py
```

Why do I receive "No module named 'project'" error when calling

```
import project.module1
```

from module2.py?

As far as I can tell, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) say this should work.

Comment: Do you have a typo or is one of your folders called "project.py"?

Comment: Typo indeed. Fixed now.